# Set up a scheduled task programmatically

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-7, installation, scheduled-tasks

My application needs to set up a scheduled task on installation. The task is to run my program on several triggers (related to logon events). I am wondering what is the easiest way to do this? Should I use a batch file?

This program will run only on Windows 7.

Comment: What installer are you using?

Comment: Right now I am using an installer project from within Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds more like a WindowsService than a scheduled task. The [SystemEvents Class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.aspx) includes an example of setting up a WindowsService that will then monitor for various system events (including SessionEnding and SessionSwitch). Monitoring for *logon* events would be difficult as you have something of a chicken/egg problem there. On the other hand, adding an application to run on startup is relatively simple and would let you know that a user has logged on...